# SAS - Drop observations once a condition is met, by ID

Tags: sas

For each ID, I want to drop all observations that come after a dummy variable takes the value 1. An example would be:

The data I have:

```
ID  TIME    DUMMY 
1   1       0
1   2       0
1   3       1
1   4       0
2   1       0
2   2       0
2   3       1
3   1       1
3   2       0
3   3       0
```

The output I want:

```
ID  TIME    DUMMY 
1   1       0
1   2       0
1   3       1
2   1       0
2   2       0
2   3       1
3   1       1
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? The question is not really clear, how many observations do you want to drop. Because after the first DUMMY=1, you dropped one observation. But then you dropped two observations in the end of data set..

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; for a given ID, I want to drop all observations after a dummy variable takes the value 1. That is why in my example the number of observations dropped varies depending on the ID.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it:

```
data want(drop = a);
  set have;
  by id;
  retain a;
  if first.id then a = 1;
  if a = 1 then output;
  if dummy = 1 then a = 0;
run;
```

Comment: The third to last line should read:

if lag(dummy) = 1 then a = 0;

thanks!

Comment: If you have two consecutive IDs with a single row each with dummy =1, your lag condition would delete the second one when you actually want to keep it. The fix I've made above avoids doing this.

Comment: Looks okay, but I'd use a better variable name to be clear (not `a` as a trigger).

Answer (score 1):

Using a dow-loop seems more elegant than retain and lag.
Read more about this programming structure here: http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2011/SS01.Dorfman.pdf
It's very useful.

```
data want(drop=printit);
    if 0 then set have;
    printit = last.id;
    do until(last.id or dummy);
        set have;
        by id;
        if printit then output;
    end;
run;
```

The line before the `do` statement is just to keep the columns in the original order.

Comment: How does `if printit then output;` result in any record other than the last one in each ID by group being output?

Comment: First thing to understand is that there are 2 loops in effect there. The implicit loop of the whole data step and the explicit do loop.
There are two alternative conditions to exit the do loop, either the by-group ended (so last.id = 1) or when dummy = 1.
After exiting the internal loop, execution goes back to the rows above the do statement and printit is updated: 0 if the do loop exited because of dummy and 1 if because of last.id.
So records that come after dummy=1 and before a by-group change are ignored.

Use `put _all_;` right before the do statement to see what's happening.

Comment: If the very first row has dummy = 0, and it isn't the only one in a by group, how does it get output? From my reading of it, the explicit do loop would go right through to the last row in the by group and output only that one. Then printit would be set to 1 before starting the loop again for the next group.

I'd be grateful if you could expand your answer a bit (as per your own suggestion) to explain how it's working, as this will help people understand it better.

Comment: Conveniently, last.id is 1 before the first iteration by default, so printit = 1. The until condition is only evaluated after executing the do block, so last.id is updated to 0 when it happens.
Dummy doesn't play any role in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the help of the `OUTPUT`, `RETAIN` and `RETURN` statements to override the `DATA` step loop. The `RETURN` statement forces the `DATA` step to go to the next iteration immediately. This should drop all the observations between the DUMMYs = 1 observations:

```
data want;
    set test;
    drop count;
    if DUMMY = 1 then do;
        retain count;
        count = 1;
        output;
        return;
    end;

    if count = 1 and DUMMY ne 1 then do;
        retain count;
        delete;
        return;
    end;
    output;

run;
```

OUTPUT:

```
                                ID    TIME    DUMMY

                                 1      1       0
                                 1      2       0
                                 1      3       1
                                 2      3       1
                                 3      1       1
```

Comment: This does not answer my original question. Your output does not match the one shown in the question. One correct way of doing it has been suggested by user667489, along with the modification I proposed. Thanks

Comment: You said you wanted all observations after a DUMMY variable takes the value of 1 to be dropped..

Comment: @YickLeung For ID = 2 you've deleted two observations *before* dummy takes the value of 1.